# computing groebner basis in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am completely new in Matlab and want to compute groebner basis of some polynomials.

I just wrote the following code in a new window in Matlab but it says gbasis is undefined!

```
syms x1 x2 x3 x4

p = [x1^2-x1, x2^2-x2, x3^2-x3, x4^2-x4,x1+x3-1, x2+x4-1,
x1*x2, x1*x1, x2*x2, x3*x4, x3*x3, x4*x4];

grobnerBasis = gbasis(p,'MonomialOrder','lexicographic')
```

What should I do?!

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

`gbasis` is a function that you don't have installed in Matlab.

The only version I could find is part of Mathworks, which appears to be a math library that costs money:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/gbasis.html

If you know the equation for gbasis you could write your own function. Here are instructions:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-functions-in-files.html